# Does Keras normalize kernel weights?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

As the title states, does Keras (w. Tensorflow backend) normalize the kernel weights compared to e.g. Tensorflow? For example, if two identical networks are implemented with Keras respectively Tensorflow, will the kernel-weights differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Tensorflow in backend of Keras, there are no reasons for the implementation to be different.
You can check by yourself here : https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/master/keras/layers